# Data modeling in NoSQL Databases ( Cassandra DB )

Tags: database, mongodb, cassandra, nosql, data-modeling

I am currently working on the specification stage of a project involving a NoSQL database (Apache Cassandra to be specific).

As many of you I guess had experienced, I have to make a trade offs between normalization and data duplication.

In my case I am willing to do lot of analytics and data fetching fast so my data will be completely de-normalized and we duplicate data accross tables ( what we loose on writes, we gain on reads )

Consider this user table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   user_id UUID,
   first_name TEXT,
   last_name TEXT,
   profile_pic TEXT,
   PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

the fields : `first_name, last_name`. can be used and duplicated many times on different tables, sometimes with difference field names, like: `creator_first_name, poster_first_name, taker_first_name, contributor_first_name`, ... to name few.

Here is the fun part.

- How I maintain data consistency accross many duplicates of data in a dozens of tables ( families, collections, ... call them what you want) ?
- Should I think about extra functionalities in my backend to assure writing and updating duplicate parts of my application in database ?
- Is it better to maintain consistency in backend level by adding more code or at database level ( cassandra has Batch statements for example) ?
- Are there any time proof patterns used and agreed upon by the community ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to end up writing many times in the application level across many of these tables in order to maintain consistency.

A similiar approach is to have a queue in the backend of 'names changed' and have a background service go and update all the appropriate tables.  This will mean a bit of a delay but will likely be safer overall.

Additionally you can have user_id in those tables inplace of name and have something like redis infront of cassandra to cache the user's names.  When drilling exploring a user profile go straight to the source.  That said, initially i would just read from cassandra, this would be a performance improvement.  Reddit has a blog post on 'how we build /r/place`: https://redditblog.com/2017/04/13/how-we-built-rplace/

**DO NOT** use batch inserts.  These are not atomic inserts.  If one fails, the job fails, but some or all of your inserts may have been written to some of the nodes.